# wx.EVT_IDLE set custom waiting time

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm currently using a binding to wx.EVT_IDLE to constantly redraw my scene. However I noticed this only redraws once every second. Is there any way to set the time it has to wait in order to consider an idle event to 0.1 sec or 0.01 sec?

Regards,

Bogdan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `OnIdle(self, event)` handler, you can use `event.RequestMore()` to keep generating idle events. This should allow you to redraw as fast as you can process the events. See http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.IdleEvent-class.html#RequestMore